# Adding a higher-priority route allows communication?

Tags: raspberry-pi, routing, raspbian, route

So for some reason I am having connection issues with my raspberry pi. The weird thing is that I can easily ping everything else I have on the local network. I "solved" it in the end by manually adding a route, but I'd like to find out the root cause.

You can see what commands I issued and how suddenly that one route fixes things:

```
$ ping 192.168.0.109
PING 192.168.0.109 (192.168.0.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=6.45 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=2.56 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.109: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=5.19 ms
^C
--- 192.168.0.109 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.566/4.739/6.454/1.621 ms

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2040ms

$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

$ sudo route add -net default gw 192.168.0.1 netmask 0.0.0.0 dev eth0 metric 0 

$ sudo route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=32.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=31.5 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=30.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=55 time=29.2 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 29.255/30.865/32.061/1.060 ms
```

Just in case here are my router's routes:

```
ID  Destination     Network         Subnet Mask   Gateway Interface
1   192.168.0.0     255.255.255.0   0.0.0.0       LAN & WLAN
2   192.168.11.0    255.255.255.0   0.0.0.0       Internet Connection
3   0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         192.168.11.1 Internet Connection
```

Any ideas? Suggestions?

UPDATE (as requested):

```
$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable                                                                 
$ ifconfig eth0        
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::219:bbff:fe00:0000 [censored last part of MAC]  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether [censored]  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 17 
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8    
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
$ ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
$ ip route            
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
$ route    
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 virbr0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
$ ip route show table all
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.0 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::219:bbff:fe00:0000 [censored last part of MAC] dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local metric 256 pref medium
$ sudo ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
$ sudo ip route show table all
169.254.0.0/16 dev virbr0 scope link metric 1000 linkdown 
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
broadcast 127.0.0.0 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
local 127.0.0.1 dev lo table local proto kernel scope host src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 127.255.255.255 dev lo table local proto kernel scope link src 127.0.0.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.0 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local 192.168.122.1 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope host src 192.168.122.1 
broadcast 192.168.122.255 dev virbr0 table local proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1 linkdown 
local ::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
local ::1 dev lo table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
local fe80::219:bbff:fe00:0000 [censored last part of MAC] dev eth0 table local proto kernel metric 0 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eth0 table local metric 256 pref medium           
$ sudo ip route get 8.8.8.8
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable          
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.105 netmask 255.255.255.0
$ sudo ip route get 8.8.8.8                                
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable                                         
$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.0.1 eth0
$ sudo ip route get 8.8.8.8                    
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.105 uid 0 
    cache 
$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=28.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=30.8 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.813/29.841/30.870/1.042 ms
```

Comment: How did you add default route first time? I mean who or what add first default route? Default route can be easily added by: `ip route add default via 192.168.0.1`.

Comment: I didn't add it, it came when the pi booted up via DHCP as far as I know.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `ip route get 8.8.8.8` while it's non-functional? Also just for completeness, `ip rule` and `ip route show table all`

Comment: @Patrick I finally managed to reproduce the issue after a few reboots and power cycles. It is a bit different now though, there seems to be no connection.

Comment: Thanks for the commands though, really useful!

Comment: Unfortunately the commands you ran on the latter show a much different picture than before. The latter commands indicate there is no default gateway at all.

Comment: @Patrick
These commands allowed me to diagnose the problem when it reoccurred. It turned out to be some misconfiguration in iptables. Wiping it totally and rebuilding the incoming filter fixed the problem (for now). Super weird.